# r program changing yes/no variable to 1/0 - " variable 'medal' is not a factor"

Tags: r, variables, indicator

I am new to R. I have a categorical variable that I like to make a linear model and do prediction with it but RStudio does not let me do so unless I change the type of the variable.
How can I change the yes/no to 1/0?
my error is 
" variable 'medal' is not a factor"
I have tried :

```
> sport$medal <- factor(sport$medal)
> is.factor(sport$medal)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the obvious typo...

> How can I change the yes/no to 0/1?

You need

```
sport$medal <- factor(sport$medal, levels = c("yes", "no"))
```

The default behaviour will give you 0 for "no" and 1 for "yes", as "n" comes ahead of "y" in alphabetical order.

Comment: Now > is.factor(sport$medal)
[1] TRUE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the yes/no with 1/0 use the ifelse()

```
sport$medal <- ifelse(sport$medal == "yes", 1, 0)
```

Comment: Or simply `as.integer(sport$medal == "yes")`