# Function in R - Transforming A Yes/No variable in a 1/0 variable

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I need to set a function that help me in restore the Yes/No variable in 0/1 one.

A function should be

```
x<-function(DataFrame,VariableName,Yes,No){
   .....
  }
```

I set up this code but run only out the function because R do not read the variable setted in () after the dollar sign.

```
dummy<-function(DB,varr){
        BD$varr <- as.character(DB$varr)
        DB[BD$varr=="Yes"]<-"1"
        DB[BD$varr=="No"]<-"0"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change a value coded as "Yes" to a value of 1 in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033960/how-do-i-change-a-value-coded-as-yes-to-a-value-of-1-in-r) . Replace 2 with 0 everywhere in any of the answer. Or [r program changing yes/no variable to 1/0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944567/r-program-changing-yes-no-variable-to-1-0-variable-medal-is-not-a-factor)

Comment: Use `[` instead of `$`.

Comment: `x<-function(DataFrame,VariableName,Yes) { as.integer(DataFrame[VariableName]==Yes) }` should do for your overall question.

Comment: For its use: `DB$Varr <- x(DB,"Varr","Yes")`. As an advice:don't try to update an external object in a function, even if you exactly know the caveats behind this idea, it's usually brittle and a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `as.integer` to coerce the `logical` vector to binary

```
as.integer(BD$varr=="Yes")
```